# Enterprise Architect Error : Unexpected symbol fix?

Tags: c++, macros, enterprise-architect

I am trying to generate UML diagrams by importing C++ files.
So I Right-Click the my project folder then go to Code Engineering->Import Source Directory choose the folder with all the C++ files. So far so good?

I get this error message:

```
There was an error parsing C:/path/to/file on line X. Unexpected symbol: typedef
You may need to define a language macro.
```

Which I thought I did by following [this](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/languagemacros.html) and adding `typedef`but that didn't do anything.

I'm really new to EA. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EA parses C/C++, **not** the C preprocessor language.

Thus, any macros in the file must be managed before the file can be parsed by EA. One way of doing that is to define all the macros from the file in EA as outlined in the help page you linked; this causes EA to recognize and ignore those macros.

The other alternative is to run the file through the preprocessor to resolve the macros, and then send the actual C/C++ source file to EA.

Answer (score 3):

`typedef` is not a macro but a normal C language construct. EA's parser stumbled over a hurdle somewhere **before** this `typedef` and fell on its face. So look out for other macro uses before that line.

Comment: The same happened to me on a "protected:" line in a class, when in fact the parser did not recognize our macro which switches between __declspec(dllimport) and __declspec(dllexport) (we use the same header files for compiling and publishing). Looks like the parser is like older compilers which always showed errors in the following line rather than the erroneous line

Comment: @TimMeyer You might send a bug report to Sparx. But you need to be very patient in waiting for an eventual fix.